# how to update a record with the dbf module

Tags: python, python-3.x, dbf, xbase

How can I update a record in a dbf with the dbf module : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf

Here is what I tried:

```
table2 = dbf.Table(filename, codepage="cp1252")
table[0].name = "changed"
```

But I get:

```
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/dbf/ver_33.py", line 2508, in __setattr__
    raise DbfError("unable to modify fields individually except in `with` or `Process()`")
dbf.ver_33.DbfError: unable to modify fields individually except in `with` or `Process()`
```

I managed to read and append but not to modify data, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing data to records can be accomplished in a few different ways:

- using the record as a context manager:

  `with table[0] as rec:
       rec.name = "changed"`
- using the `dbf.Process` function to deal with several records in a loop:

  `for rec in Process(my_table):
       rec.name = rec.name.title()`
- using the `write` function in the `dbf` module:

  `dbf.write(some_record, name='My New Name')`

I did it this way to enhance both safety and performance.

Comment: thanks a lot for the info but what were the reasons for this "strange" way to write to a dbf file ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, soo I didn't understand the "with or process" part but here is how I managed to get my way:

```
dbf.write(table[0],name="changed")
```

found there, this fork had more documentation https://bitbucket.org/ltvolks/python-dbase

this should be safer [Search in DBF and update record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31409565/search-in-dbf-and-update-record?rq=1)