# Python lambda issue

Tags: python, lambda

I'm trying to update a field in a *.dbf file.

For this I have created a function inspired from [Search in DBF and update record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31409565/search-in-dbf-and-update-record).

My function look like this:

```
def read_one_db_fox_record(database, collName, colMatch):
    path = 'c://'
    db = dbf.Table(path +database+'.dbf')
    db = db.open(mode=dbf.READ_WRITE)

    with db:

        x = lambda rec,col=collName: (rec.col)
        #Problem is somewhere here

        procod_idx = db.create_index(x)
        match = procod_idx.search(match=(colMatch))
        record = match[0]
        logging.debug(record)
        db.close()
```

Call:

```
read_one_db_fox_record('db', 'keye', '1')
```

Output:

```
raise FieldMissingError(name)
FieldMissingError: 'col:  no such field in table'
```

Why lamba is not passing collName value to col? I was expecting lambda to call rec.keye.

Comment: what is this `(rec.col)` supposed to do?

Comment: the argument `col` has nothing to do with the attribute access `rec.col`, you probably want `getattr(rec, col)` this has nothing to do with lambdas, which are just functions (and would work the same with normal functions - or with no functions at all)

Comment: It supposed to select the table column for index

Comment: Can you post the full error trace?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga is right. Thank you for your rapid response.